# What is the server command to change Mann Missions?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration, tf2-mann-vs-machine

In TF2's new Mann Mode, each of the levels has at least [3 different missions](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Mann_vs._Machine_mission) that the team can play against.  I assume the various **Missions** are different robot wave templates.

Lately my wife and I have been running a Mann Mode server, but I can't seem to google how to switch to any other than the default normal Mann missions.

I'm curious what is the server command to switch Mann mode missions?

How does a server admin switch Mann vs Machine missions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default you can call a vote to change the mission difficulty, although this requires a majority to change. This option is called `sv_vote_issue_mvm_challenge_allowed` and should be set to 1 for this to work.

If you wish to change via console command use `tf_mvm_skill` with 3 being normal and 5 being advanced2. Although this console command requires `sv_cheats 1` to be set. This means no achievement can be got until it is set back to 0 and the map is restarted.

Comment: Nice, I assume 4 is advanced1.

Answer (score 6):

make a cfg file for all 3 MvM maps:

```
mvm_coaltown.cfg, mvm_decoy.cfg, mvm_mannworks.cfg
```

use this format to force modes:

```
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_mannworks_ironman"
```

variables:

```
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_mannworks"             // Manouvers (invasion, easy)
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_mannworks_advanced"    // Machine Massacre (invasion, normal)
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_mannworks_ironman"     // Mech Mutilation (endurance, expert)
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_coaltown"              // Crash Course (invasion, easy)
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_coaltown_advanced"     // Ctrl+Alt+Destruction (invasion, normal)
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_coaltown_advanced2"    // CPU Slaughter (invasion, advanced)
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_decoy"                 // Doe's Drill (invasion, easy)
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_decoy_advanced"        // Disk Deletion (invasion, advanced)
tf_mvm_popfile "mvm_decoy_advanced2"       // Data Demolition (invasion, advanced)
```