# What is the command to call a vote to change Mann Missions?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

In my previous question [What is the server command to change Mann Missions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/81243/3128) I ask how to change Mann Missions, and I learn that one must normally call a vote.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to craft the command to vote to change Mann Missions.  I tried typing in anything I could find in the selected answer, but nothing.  Also google didn't find me anything.

What is the command to call for a vote to change Mann Missions in TF2's Mann vs Machine mode?

Comment: Are you sure this is a default option? If it's a server-specific mod (Like Rock The Vote), it may not be possible in vanilla servers.

Comment: I saw someone do it the other day.  I think you can do it whenever, but it can probably be disabled, perhaps.  I could be wrong though.  Either way, there IS a command to issue the vote.  At least I think there is, lol.

Comment: do you need it to be a command from the console? there are GUI buttons available to call votes.

Comment: @Colin D - What buttons are those? To my knowledge there isn't a callvote gui button on a vanilla server.

Comment: @Colin D - I just verified by looking around the interface for any buttons, but I could not find any gui buttons for callvote, therefore I have to assume there are no such buttons.

Comment: @MarkRogers I didn't realize this vote calling was wanted from the server interface, I do not have any experience using the server program. The buttons exist on the tf2 client, see my answer below.

Comment: @ColinD - Your correct, I didn't think about that button, its only visible after joining, good catch, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to call a vote from the console? If not, there is an easy way to call a vote from the UI. I do not know if it allows you to select custom maps or anything, but its worth a shot.

From a game: it the 'escape' button to bring up the main menu. Then on the 'resume game' button there are a couple of sub-buttons. the 'checkmark'/'tick' is the call vote button.

http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Main_menu#Start_Playing.2FResume_Game

Answer (score 0):

One simply uses the command `callvote` from the console window, and when you leave the console there will be a list of voting options including the option to change the **Mann mission** for the current **MVM** level.

One may also **bind** a key to a callvote button in the keyboard options or by console command, but one is not bound by default.

I was confused because I had forgotten that the default vote-calling options are routed through the `callvote` command.  A command I had sadly forgotten, because I was used to the magical vote commands common to most modded servers.

Comment: Isn't callvote bound to a key by default?

Comment: @kotekzot - No, it is unmapped by default.